# Правильный вывод showMiniCart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Нужна помощь, есть функция

```
function showMiniCart(){
    //показываю содержимое корзины
    var out ='';
    for (var key in cart) {
        out += Object.keys(cart).reduce((total, key) => total += cart[key], 0);
    }
    $('#mini-cart').html(out);
}
```

Проблема в том, что выводит она не совсем, верно то, что хотелось, а именно, в корзину попадет:
Если добавлю 1 товар то все нормально складывает, но при добавлении 2 товара, результат складывается и выводит рядом еще раз.

Пример: 1 товар - вывод 1, 2 товара - вывод 22, 3 товара - выводит 333.

Comment: `var out = 0;` *(2 символа нужно...)*

Comment: var out = 0; пробовал, никак не помогает. Считает теперь странно вообще. Может вообще иначе нужно функцию построить, чтобы складывало товары?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите + в строке

```
for (var key in cart) {
    out = Object.keys(cart).reduce((total, key) => total += cart[key], 0);
}
```

вы конкатенируете строки, а исходя из задачи у вас должно получаться новое значение

Comment: +
вот блин...долгий рабочий день дает о себе знать.

Comment: @Ivan если мое сообщение вам помогло, то вы можете отметить его как правильный ответ)

Comment: Все хорошо,но нашел ошибку)в ie Object.keys не поддерживается, не посоветуете как решить иначе тогда?)

Comment: @Ivan если вам нужно толкьо кол-во товаров в корзине, попробуйте использовать Object.length. 

хотя мне кажется хорошим решением будет сделать вот так 
$('#mini-cart').html(cart.length); - насколько я понял в cart лежат товары в виде объектов